# Limits of a Publisher when a topic and writer is conserned

Tags: c, build.xml, data-distribution-service

Could anyone let me know if one publisher can be used for passing different parameters (Data Types), like integer, float, string, char etc...

Does Open Splice DDS Community edition have any limitations for publishers? If so how many publishers can it accommodate?

```
<OpenSplice>
<Domain>
<Name>ospl_sp_ddsi</Name>
<Id>0</Id>
<SingleProcess>true</SingleProcess>
<Service name="ddsi2">
<Command>ddsi2</Command>
</Service>
<Service name="durability">
<Command>durability</Command>
</Service>
<Service enabled="false" name="cmsoap">
<Command>cmsoap</Command>
</Service>
</Domain>
<DDSI2Service name="ddsi2">
<General>   
<NetworkInterfaceAddress>192.168.147.179</NetworkInterfaceAddress>
<AllowMulticast>true</AllowMulticast>
<EnableMulticastLoopback>true</EnableMulticastLoopback>
<CoexistWithNativeNetworking>false</CoexistWithNativeNetworking>
</General>
<Compatibility>
<!-- see the release notes and/or the OpenSplice configurator on DDSI    interoperability -->
<StandardsConformance>lax</StandardsConformance>
<!-- the following one is necessary only for TwinOaks CoreDX DDS compatibility -->
<!--      <ExplicitlyPublishQosSetToDefault>true</ExplicitlyPublishQosSetToDefault> -->
</Compatibility>
</DDSI2Service>
<DurabilityService name="durability">
  <Network>
     <Alignment>
        <TimeAlignment>false</TimeAlignment>
        <RequestCombinePeriod>
           <Initial>2.5</Initial>
           <Operational>0.1</Operational>
        </RequestCombinePeriod>
     </Alignment>
     <WaitForAttachment maxWaitCount="10">
        <ServiceName>ddsi2</ServiceName>
     </WaitForAttachment>
  </Network>
  <NameSpaces>
     <NameSpace name="defaultNamespace">
        <Partition>*</Partition>
     </NameSpace>
     <Policy alignee="Initial" aligner="true" durability="Durable"     nameSpace="defaultNamespace"/>
 </NameSpaces>
 </DurabilityService>
 <TunerService name="cmsoap">
  <Server>
     <PortNr>none</PortNr>
  </Server>
</TunerService>
</OpenSplice>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DDS-publisher can have multiple writers of different topics where each topic-type can include various parameters of various types (including bounded and unbounded types such as arrays and sequences).

The OpenSplice CE (Community Edition) doesn't have any limitation for publishers, but when you want to run more than 10 applications on a single machine you have to change the DDSI/Discovery/ParticipantIndex parameter from its default 'auto' value to 'none', see also this post: http://forums.opensp...index#entry4024

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Is there any link describing the implementation of round trip on different PCs?
 
If so could you please let me know